# how can I set a readonly attribute on a strongly typed checkbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

how can i set a readonly attribute to a strongly typed checkbox? i tried the following:

<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Field1, new {@readonly="true" })%>

i cant use a disabled property because this is not posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using your custom javascript or jQuery, or you can set it to disabled (it will be readonly, but greyed)

new {@disabled="disabled" }

Comment: but this value wont be posted to the server?